# Accessing array of object in Angular 2 Observable

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm new to Angular 2. I have an observable object, called employees. How to extract the Employee array from that Observable? 
(let's say, because I need to perform operation on particular index) :

```
employees:Observable<Employees[]>;
```

And I'm intended to be

```
empArr:Employee[];
empArr = employees.somethingToConvertToArray(); // this is what I intended
```

I've tried with .subscribe or .map, but I think I'm going to wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how it works. To get data from an observable, you subscribe to it

```
employees.subscribe(val => this.empArray = val);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that and put log inside arrow function and it works. However this.empArray back to undefined outside that statement.

Comment: That's expected behavior. You have to move all the code inside the callback. You can use `val => { ... }` to be able to add multiple statements. `val => ...` is a function passed to `subscribe(...)` and subscribe calls this function whenever a new value becomes available. Code outside of this function is executed before a value becomes available.

Comment: Just like Günther said, as addition I thought I'd just throw this one out there, which explains this behavior a bit :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/43055707/6294072

Comment: Why it does not work for me: `this.newEducationYearModel = new  Observable<CreateEducationYear>();
    this.newEducationYearModel.subscribe(val => console.log(val));`

Comment: I get an error: `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Comment: @user3573738 You can use a `Subject` instead https://plnkr.co/edit/nWxSFqhoCWVmbj9IwkDM?p=preview. Check also https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html for an `Observable` example.

Comment: What is Subject, instead Subject I have own custom model: CreateEducationYear:{id: 1, name: "ok"} on which I need subscribe.

Comment: `Subject` is a convenient way to create observables. You can just call `this.mySubject.next(someEventValue);` to emit new values.

Comment: Can you  share extended sample please? With custom complicated model?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with custom complicated model. I don't see how a model would be involved here. Perhaps it's better to create a new question with the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: This is my full code: `public newEducationYearModel: Observable<CreateEducationYear>; this.newEducationYearModel = new  Observable<CreateEducationYear>(); public test(): Observable<CreateEducationYear> {
    return this.newEducationYearModel;
  }  And calling: ngOnInit() {
    this.test().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }`

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of that. I don't see why just using a `Subject` instead of `Observable` wouldn't work for that. Have you even tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152174/discussion-between-user3573738-and-gunter-zochbauer).